# Valgrind detect error when allocating using realloc and strdup

Tags: c, memory, valgrind

So far my program have been working quite well, I wanted to run valgrind to be sure I had not forgotten any free/malloc. However, Valgrind reported errors where I believe there are none.

Here's a code snippet to reproduce the error :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    /* Init the array to NULL for realloc */
    char **name_array = NULL;
    int nb_names =0;

    /* Allocate the first name and add it to the array */
    name_array = realloc(name_array, sizeof(char *));
    name_array[nb_names] = strdup("Hello World!\n");
    nb_names++;


    /* Allocate the second name and add it to the array */
    name_array = realloc(name_array, sizeof(char *));
    name_array[nb_names] = strdup("This is a test!\n");

    /* Print the names */
    printf (name_array[0]);
    printf (name_array[1]);

    /* Free the strdup'd names and the array */
    free(name_array[0]);
    free(name_array[1]);
    free(name_array);
}
```

This is the program output :

```
Hello World!
This is a test!
```

Here is the Valgrind output:

```
==31585== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==31585== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==31585== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==31585== Command: ./a.out --leak-check=full
==31585== 
==31585== Invalid write of size 4
==31585==    at 0x10538: main (in /home/pi/tmp/a.out)
==31585==  Address 0x49830a4 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==31585==    at 0x48358A0: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:632)
==31585==    by 0x10517: main (in /home/pi/tmp/a.out)
==31585== 
Hello World!
==31585== Invalid read of size 4
==31585==    at 0x10554: main (in /home/pi/tmp/a.out)
==31585==  Address 0x49830a4 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==31585==    at 0x48358A0: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:632)
==31585==    by 0x10517: main (in /home/pi/tmp/a.out)
==31585== 
This is a test!
==31585== Invalid read of size 4
==31585==    at 0x10578: main (in /home/pi/tmp/a.out)
==31585==  Address 0x49830a4 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==31585==    at 0x48358A0: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:632)
==31585==    by 0x10517: main (in /home/pi/tmp/a.out)
==31585== 
==31585== 
==31585== HEAP SUMMARY:
==31585==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31585==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 39 bytes allocated
==31585== 
==31585== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==31585== 
==31585== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==31585== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I've searched other Q&A about this answer, usually folks forgets the allocate the null byte.

I know realloc can cause memory leaks when theres no memory left, I should first assign the result of realloc to a temporary variable, check that the returned value is not null then assign the temporary variable to my true variables.

Appart from the possible leak when realloc fails, is there any mistake in this program ?

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks guys for the quick answers.

For the record here is the corrected code:

```
    /* Allocate the first name and add it to the array */
    name_array = realloc(name_array, sizeof(char *) * ++nb_names);
    name_array[nb_names -1] = strdup("Hello World!\n");


    /* Allocate the second name and add it to the array */
    name_array = realloc(name_array, sizeof(char *) * ++nb_names);
    name_array[nb_names -1] = strdup("This is a test!\n");

    /* Print the names */
    printf (name_array[0]);
    printf (name_array[1]);
```

And the valgrind output :

```
==32105== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==32105== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==32105== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==32105== Command: ./a.out
==32105== 
Hello World!
This is a test!
==32105== 
==32105== HEAP SUMMARY:
==32105==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==32105==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 43 bytes allocated
==32105== 
==32105== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==32105== 
==32105== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==32105== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Good day to you all.

Comment: Your second realloc doesn't increase the size of the array.

Comment: `name_array = realloc(name_array, sizeof(char *));` => `name_array = realloc(name_array, sizeof *name_array * ++nb_names);`.

Comment: Also, `name_array = realloc(name_array, ...)` is a potential memory leak. And check that `malloc()` did not return `NULL`.

Comment: Note that you should compile with -g, otherwise valgrind error messages cannot point at the source file and line nr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this (second) call:

```
name_array = realloc(name_array, sizeof(char *));
```

You are still allocating just one char pointer. So, you can't store two pointers; you need to increase the size:

```
name_array = realloc(name_array, 2 * sizeof *name_array);
```

Now, you'd be fine.

Note that `p = realloc(p, ..);` style of realloc() could lead to memory leaks if `realloc()` fails.

Also, you'd be better off using a format string to avoid pontential format string attack (if it's going to be user inputted):

```
   /* Print the names */
    printf ("%s\n", name_array[0]);
    printf ("%s\n", name_array[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is better reported by address sanitizer than valgrind. If you compile your code like:

```
gcc test.c -fsanitize=address -g
```

and then run it, it will report heap-buffer-overflow error in line 19 of your code. This is the line where you assign second element of name_array having allocated memory for only one element.

Comment: Unfortunately I think my gcc version is too (gcc raspbian v4.9.2-10) old for these flags. In my distrust of valgrind I compiled my code with all the possible fsanitize flags without result. Turned out valgrind was right in the end, how surprising.